# Using Virtual PC for Web Development with Oracle

Tags: performance, virtual-pc

Is anyone using Virtual PC to maintain multiple large .NET 1.1 and 2.0 websites?  Are there any lessons learned?  I used Virtual PC recently with a small WinForms app and it worked great, but then everything works great with WinForms.  ASP.NET development hogs way more resources, requires IIS to be running, requires a ridiculously long wait after recompilations, etc., so I'm a little concerned.  And I'll also be using Oracle, if that makes any difference.

Also, is there any real reason to use VM Ware instead of Virtual PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used VirtualPCs for a few years for development of some fairly hefty web apps without much problem.  Lots of RAM is important.  I keep my VPCs on an external USB drive and they perform great from there.  This gives me the flexibility to take the drive with me if I need to do work somewhere else...  just install VPC on a host plug in the USB drive and start coding.

For servers, we use VMWare and have had little to no trouble with it.

Recently I went back to working on my local machine as you lose the benefit of dual monitors with VPCs, and I don't need to be as mobile as I used to.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the resources (separate hard disk for the virtual machine, sufficient RAM), I don't see why you would have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual PC 2007 is very fast esp on a CPU that has hardware support for VM's. 3GB RAM a must for anything not small. XP makes a good guest OS, Vista works well as a host.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.  So RAM is the key.

As far as dual monitor capability, I found that I could use dual monitors, as long as one of those monitors was my actual machine.  And that was what I wanted anyway.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using VPCs as a server...perhaps Hyper-V (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Virtualization) is something to look at.

Its pretty powerful, in how it lets you assign RAM / CPU Cores to a virtualized machine.